# Root login in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: root

Can you please let me know how can I login graphically using root account in Ubuntu Desktop 17.10. I have tried several ways but none worked. Please help.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo . I do not think root logins are supported by gnome or ubuntu.

Comment: What do you need that for? Sounds like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) problem. The site @Panther refers to says ***Logging in to X as root may cause very serious trouble.***

Comment: *"I have tried several ways but none worked."* I recommend that you **[edit]** this to describe everything you have tried and exactly what happened. Also, as others have said, it would be best also to include information about why you want this, since there may be another way to achieve some or all of your goals (and if, somehow, there is not, then your situation or goals are unusual and more information would be needed if someone is to give a good answer that satisfies you).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in wayland environment.In wayland, in case of non root login, access as root for any tool is prohibited. You should bind your self (localuser) with root previlage.To add localuser with root privilege:

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVM090gB1wo

Once you have done, you can unassign the privilege by :

```
xhost -si:localuser:root
```

The given privilege will go away if you reboot your system.